# PHP/XML feed reader where to start?

Tags: php, xml, feed

I have a question regarding XML feeds.

There is a website whitch provides data and they give me 2 links for 2 files

- file 1 : Cars_docu.atom
- file 2 : Cars.atom

date on file 1 is like this

```
 <entry>
<author>
  <name />
</author>
<f:name>Name</f:name>
<f:description>Product name</f:description>
```

and the second file is like this

```
 <entry>
<title>Volvo</title>
<link rel="alternate" href="#1" />
<author>
  <name />
</author>
<id>237370</id>
<updated>2015-08-17T11:44:32Z</updated>
<f:name>Volvo Lamp</f:name>
```

So as I understand the first file includes name of the filds and the second one includes the data

My question is what is the method of pulling this imformation from both files using a PHP file and gather them into one page ?

and inside the second document there is a 10000 product so how i pull one pacific product only?

I need methods if you have code I will be glad or just tell me where to start

regads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the SimpleXML Class:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php

The approach to take is to use file_get_contents to pull the data from the XML pages and then use SimpleXML to parse it into an array.

For example:

```
<?php

$url = "somewebsite.com/Cars.atom";

$file = file_get_contents($url);

$carsArray = new SimpleXMLElement($file);

foreach ($carsArray->entry as $car) {

   echo $car->title; // Would display "Volvo"

}

?>
```

When I'm first investigating the structure of an XML document that has been parsed into an array I find it useful to use the print_r() function.

From the above, the next simple step is to load both XML doc's and work you way through to build the data you want to display.

**Edit** if you want to match a specific item
Assuming you are wanting to match the car title to Volvo, this is how you could do it.

```
<?php

$url = "somewebsite.com/Cars.atom";

$file = file_get_contents($url);

$carsArray = new SimpleXMLElement($file);

// Need to use an array key to get the element, alternatively can loop through each value
if($carsArray->entry[0]->title == "Volvo") {
    echo "Car is a Volvo!";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is was grate, but the question is how to bring a specific item?

Comment: @DarkMarv check out my edit. Making the assumption you are wanting to match the title to a predefined value. You can essentially match any value in the array with this method you will just need to know how deep you need to go etc. This is also making some assumptions around the consistency of data ie. I am assuming entry->title will always exist.

Comment: Grate this solve my problem but there is only one last question

some filds are like 
<id>1038184</id>
<f:name>volvo</f:name>

so how could I pull information in this case , becuase this not working ($carsArray->f:name)

Comment: @DarkMarv Without looking at the full XML I assuming it is formed correctly. The colon (:) indicates it is using a XML namespace. You need to use the getNamespaces method. See this example in the comment on the php documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getnamespaces.php#107562

Comment: Not a problem - happy to help

Comment: Last question :) 
How to get a specific result when using getNamespaces  ! it shows all the result i only need to get one

Comment: In the example I pointed you to in the PHP Manual - the last foreach loop `foreach ($child as $out)` you would put an if statement in that foreach loop, for example `if($out == "Volvo") echo "It's a volvo";`. Alternatively you could use the in_array() function to do the test outside of the for loop.

Comment: yes it works, thanks again ..
I wanted to open new question but the stackoverflow system did not allowed me ..

any way my code now is
 `
foreach ($carsArray as $out_ns) 
{ 
    $ns = $out_ns->getNamespaces(true); 
    $child = $out_ns->children($ns['f']); 
    foreach ($child as $out) 
    { 
     if($out_ns->id == "tag:340237")
  {
     echo $out . "<br />"; 
  }
    } 
} 
`
my question is how I sort it in array.. I have a template system and each result from the array should match the item name on my template..

is it possibel ?

Comment: If you want to assign to an array - just instead of the echo $out, do the variable assignment. If there are multiple matches you could initialise an array before the for each loop - and then assign values to the array instead of the echo call.